# React Native Android bundle hangs with --dev false

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to make a React Native android bundle and it works fine with --dev true but the following command hangs with --dev false

```
# this works
node --expose-gc --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --verbose --platform android --dev true --reset-cache --entry-file index.js --bundle-output /usr/src/app/android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest /usr/src/app/android/app/src/main/res/

# this freezes
node --expose-gc --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --verbose --platform android --dev false --reset-cache --entry-file index.js --bundle-output /usr/src/app/android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest /usr/src/app/android/app/src/main/res/
```

I've already tried adding the --verbose argument but the output is pretty brief

```
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
```

Is there any way to get more information from the bundler? Or is the only way to do some printf debugging in the bundler.

FYI, i was hoping to reproduce the same problem using Haul but the Haul build passes with the following:

```
'./index.js 1:275593-275611\nCritical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression\n ...
'asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).\nThis can impact web performance.\nAssets: \n  ../assets/index.android.bundle (1.57 MiB)',
'entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.\nEntrypoints:\n  main (1.57 MiB)\n      ../assets/index.android.bundle\n',
'webpack performance recommendations: \nYou can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.\nFor more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was running the build in a Docker container which was running on Hyperkit on my Mac. Hyperkit was created via command line with a 2G memory limitation which explains why the build would keep running until it hit the 2G memory limit and then fail silently.